# Error: mkvirtualenv with python 3 install, and macbook breaking on: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv

Anyone else have issues installing and using the virtual env with Python 3x on a Mac? Since its not part of the native install, I installed python3 myself which comes with pip3.

I ran:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

I now have in my .bash_profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Added this myself
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/workspace/python
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I run the command:

```
$ mkvirtualenv myproject
```

I get this:

```
myproject/bin/python3.4

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
symlink=options.symlink)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 984, in create_environment
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1276, in install_python
shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

OSError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links: 'myproject/bin/python3.4'
```

My questions are over:

1. What does this error mean? Do I have some sort of circular link which breaks this?
2. How do I correctly install the virtualenvwrapper? I want my new Django project using the Library/...python3.4 install and I want to keep this separate from the Macs own install of 2.7.x

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as "OSError: [Errno 62] Too many levels of symbolic links"

then I found there are some symbalic links in this directory:

```
WWW:flasky Wu$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/
WWW:bin Wu$ ls
2to3            idle3           pip3.4          python3         python3.4       python3.4m      pyvenv-3.4
2to3-3.4        idle3.4         pydoc3          python3-32      python3.4-32        python3.4m-config   virtualenv
easy_install-3.4    pip3            pydoc3.4        python3-config      python3.4-config    pyvenv          virtualenv-3.4
WWW:bin Wu$ ls -l
total 288
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      8  5  1 11:53 2to3 -> 2to3-3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    147  5  1 12:28 2to3-3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    287  5  1 12:28 easy_install-3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      7  5  1 11:53 idle3 -> idle3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    145  5  1 12:28 idle3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    259  5  1 12:29 pip3
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    259  5  1 12:29 pip3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      8  5  1 11:53 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    130  5  1 12:30 pydoc3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      9  5  1 11:53 python3 -> python3.4
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     12  5  1 11:53 python3-32 -> python3.4-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16  5  1 11:53 python3-config -> python3.4-config
-rwxrwxr-x  2 root  wheel  25920  2 23 18:54 python3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  13568  2 23 18:54 python3.4-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     17  5  1 11:53 python3.4-config -> python3.4m-config
-rwxrwxr-x  2 root  wheel  25920  2 23 18:54 python3.4m
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel   2088  5  1 12:31 python3.4m-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     10  5  1 11:53 pyvenv -> pyvenv-3.4
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    282  5  1 12:24 pyvenv-3.4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    266  5  1 12:32 virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    266  5  1 12:32 virtualenv-3.4
```

When I rm these all symbolic links in bin, it works, virtualenv run successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Check first all with `ls -I` command to know loop connected with symbolic links. After that you have to remove or give the path where your Python is installed.